# What does these fields Available on Knowledge Search Activity Reports means?

Tags: knowledge

Not getting clear understanding of below fields & anyone please provide some detailed meaning of these fields & how values get calculated by the salesforce.

**Fields**

- Average Click Rank
- Duration
- Number of Results

Some time  I have seen values in decimal & so not able to get understanding how they are being calculated.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Average Click Rank - If this article showed in search results AND it was clicked by a user, what is the average position at that time? For example if it always appears in the 3rd position of a search result and someone clicks it, the average is 3. A smaller number here would mean it's near the top in the results when it's clicked, and a higher number means it's further down in results but still getting clicked.

Duration - This is basically a date filter for aggregation in your report. So you can filter it by daily, monthly, or yearly.

Number of Results - How many articles were returned for each search term or keyword. So if you want to know how many articles were returned yesterday for a search "broken printer" this is one way you could find out.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_custom_reports_fields.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks Paul. Can you please tell me scenario specifically for Number of Results & Average Click Rank where value appears in decimal like 1.5 etc.

Comment: Since it's an average over the duration you specify, it won't always be an integer value. For example if you run two searches and one has 5 results and one has 6 results, your Number of Results will be 5.5.